# How do i turn an array of strings into objects?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a class Team{}.
I have an array of strings $teams = array('team1', 'team2', 'team3').
I want to loop through the array and create an object with each string as the object name.

```
class Team{}

$teams = array('team1', 'team2', 'team3');

foreach ($teams as $team) {
    $team = new Team();
}
```

So $team1, $team2 and $team3 becomes object.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Either use the key to access the array and assign the object or use the value by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Team has a property `"name"` just do it like this:

```
class Team {

  private $yourPropertyForName;

  public function __construct($name) {
    $this->yourPropertyForName = $name;
    //initialise the rest of your properties
  }
}

$teamList = [];    
$teams = array('team1', 'team2', 'team3');

foreach ($teams as $teamName) {
   array_push($teamList, new Team($teamName));
}
//teamList now contains the three Team objects
```

Comment: My original code already has multiple properties for the Team class such as name, location etc. Will this still work?

Comment: Yes just change the constructor accordingly, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this just another "$" symbol for the team variable would give what you are expecting.

<?php
    Class Team{}    
    $teams = array('team1', 'team2', 'team3');    
    foreach ($teams as $team) {
       $$team = new Team();
    }
    var_dump($team1);
    var_dump($team2);
    var_dump($team3);    
?>
```

Which outputs like 
object(Team)#1 (0) { } object(Team)#2 (0) { } object(Team)#3 (0) { }

as you are expecting :)